# Create a On-click event from HTML to JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery

I want to open a chat (already scripted in my header) when I click on a button using jquery.

I have the code working using HTML but I'm willing to translate it into jquery. But I'm not familiar with it, nor to write it.

```
<div class="XXX" id"YYY" onclick="customPlugin.command('WebChat.open');">Start Tchat</a></div>
```

Here is what i came from but it's not working :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("XXX").on("click", function customPlugin.command('WebChat.open'){
     });
   });
});
```

I don't know where to insert my function, nor how...
Anyhelp would be very much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you should add the point for class selectors in JQuery so just write `$(".XXX")` instead

Comment: Or fix your html `id="YYY"` and use `$("#YYY")`.  Note that `jQuery(function ($) {` and `$( document ).ready(function() {` are the same, you don't need both - does not real harm, just not clean.  Like `var x = 1; x = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all to select elements by class you should use the point before the class name in JQuery

Then you need to call your function from inner anonymous function in click method, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".XXX").on("click", function() { customPlugin.command('WebChat.open') });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly as intended. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Jean-FélixComet-Barthe accept the answer so :) press the checkmark on it.

Answer (score 0):

in line 3 of your jquery file you should write $(".XXX")

Comment: Can you please add some code to address the specific part of the code. In that way your answer will be more obvious.